# How to create Java Key Store (.jks) file with AES encryption

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, jks

Reading Oracle documentation, I see that by default JKS files are encrypted using `PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES`. While DES alone makes me feel uneasy, MD5 lights a big red light. I'd like to use `PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC` or `PBEWithSHA256And128bitAES-CBC-BC` to encrypt private keys.

Do I have to write new Cryptography Service Provider implementing whole KeyStore interface or is it possible to parametrise the creation of KeyStore (either using plain java or BouncyCastle)?

**EDIT:**
A little bit of background.

I know that 3DES isn't broken, just as is MD5 used as KDF (or in PBE). The problem is, that this is the situation for *now*. For all we know, MD5 may be broken to the level MD4 is broken tomorrow. My application life is at least 10 years, and it's very likely it's much more. Somehow I don't see people after those 10 years delving deep into *working* crypto code just because it may not be secure. One just needs to look at last few of the big "mishaps" with password leaks to see how likely is that, and that were obvious things to anyone that saw the raw database.

That being said: NSA crypto suite B allows only AES for symmetric encryption, of any kind. 
NIST list only SHA-1 and SHA-2 algorithms for HMAC and KDF use, while SHA-1 use is *not recommended*. Suite B allows *only* SHA-2 hash functions. Those algorithms are publicly available, so why shouldn't I use them?

Comment: TripleDES is not DES. [TripleDES is secure](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2231).

Comment: @mikeazo: I know that DES and tripe DES aren't the same thing, but even 3DES gives you at best 112bits of security. As for real assessment of security: NSA doesn't agree, Suite B allows only AES. Still, the bigger problem is use of MD5 and SHA-1.

Comment: _JKS_ (which most Java utitilies and programs defaulted to until 2017, when they started promoting PKCS12) doesn't use MD5&3DES, it uses a [bogus algorithm invented by Sun back in ITAR days](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/ab2e99db6702/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/KeyProtector.java). [_JCEKS_, which you had to make an effort to select, uses MD5&3DES.](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/ab2e99db6702/src/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/KeyProtector.java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I went with PKCS#8 files encrypted using `PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC`

**Encryption:**

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.AlgorithmParameters;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidParameterSpecException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.bc.BCObjectIdentifiers;

public class EncodePKCS8 {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException 
 * @throws InvalidKeySpecException 
 * @throws NoSuchPaddingException 
 * @throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException 
 * @throws InvalidKeyException 
 * @throws BadPaddingException 
 * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException 
 * @throws InvalidParameterSpecException 
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws NoSuchProviderException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
InvalidParameterSpecException, IOException, NoSuchProviderException
{
    // before we can do anything with BouncyCastle we have to register its provider
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

    String password = "Very long and complex password";

    // generate RSA key pair
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

    byte[] encryptedPkcs8 = encryptPrivateKey(password, keyPair);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("privkey.p8");
    fos.write(encryptedPkcs8);
    fos.close();

    return;
}

private static byte[] encryptPrivateKey(String password, KeyPair keyPair)
    throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException,
    InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException,
    InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
    BadPaddingException, InvalidParameterSpecException, IOException
{
    int count = 100000; // hash iteration count, best to leave at default or increase
    return encryptPrivateKey(password, keyPair, count);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param password
 * @param keyPair
 * @param count
 * @return PKCS#8 encoded, encrypted keyPair
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
 * @throws NoSuchProviderException
 * @throws InvalidKeySpecException
 * @throws NoSuchPaddingException
 * @throws InvalidKeyException
 * @throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
 * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
 * @throws BadPaddingException
 * @throws InvalidParameterSpecException
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static byte[] encryptPrivateKey(String password, 
        KeyPair keyPair, int count) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeySpecException,
        NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException, InvalidParameterSpecException, IOException
{
    // extract the encoded private key, this is an unencrypted PKCS#8 private key
        byte[] encodedprivkey = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();

        // Use a PasswordBasedEncryption (PBE) algorithm, OID of this algorithm will be saved
        // in the PKCS#8 file, so changing it (when more standard algorithm or safer
        // algorithm is available) doesn't break backwards compatibility.
        // In other words, decryptor doesn't need to know the algorithm before it will be
        // able to decrypt the PKCS#8 object.
        String encAlg = BCObjectIdentifiers.bc_pbe_sha256_pkcs12_aes256_cbc.getId();

        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        random.nextBytes(salt);

        // Create PBE parameter set
        PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, count);
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
        SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(encAlg, "BC");
        SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

        Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance(encAlg, "BC");

        // Initialize PBE Cipher with key and parameters
        pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);

        // Encrypt the encoded Private Key with the PBE key
        byte[] ciphertext = pbeCipher.doFinal(encodedprivkey);

        // Now construct  PKCS #8 EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo object
        AlgorithmParameters algparms = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(encAlg, "BC");
        algparms.init(pbeParamSpec);
        EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encinfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(algparms, ciphertext);

        // DER encoded PKCS#8 encrypted key
        byte[] encryptedPkcs8 = encinfo.getEncoded();

        return encryptedPkcs8;
    }
}
```

**Decryption:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.AlgorithmParameters;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;

public class DecodePKCS8 {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws NoSuchPaddingException When file is corrupted
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException When no BC provider has been loaded 
     * @throws InvalidKeySpecException When decryption of file failed
     * @throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException When file is corrupted
     * @throws InvalidKeyException When Unlimited cryptography extensions are not installed
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws
    IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
    InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
    {
        // before we can do anything with BouncyCastle we have to register its provider
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

        String password = "Very long and complex password";

        // read DER encoded key from files
        byte[] encodedprivkey = getFileBytes("privkey.p8");

        // this is a encoded PKCS#8 encrypted private key
        EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo ePKInfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(encodedprivkey);

        // first we have to read algorithm name and parameters (salt, iterations) used
        // to encrypt the file
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ePKInfo.getAlgName());
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());

        SecretKeyFactory skFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ePKInfo
                .getAlgName());
        Key pbeKey = skFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

        // Extract the iteration count and the salt
        AlgorithmParameters algParams = ePKInfo.getAlgParameters();
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, algParams);

        // Decrypt the encryped private key into a PKCS8EncodedKeySpec
        KeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = ePKInfo.getKeySpec(cipher);

        // Now retrieve the RSA Public and private keys by using an
        // RSA key factory.
        KeyFactory rsaKeyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        // First get the private key
        PrivateKey rsaPriv = rsaKeyFac.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);
        // Now derive the RSA public key from the private key
        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(((RSAKey) rsaPriv).getModulus(),
                ((RSAPrivateCrtKey) rsaPriv).getPublicExponent());
        PublicKey rsaPubKey = (RSAPublicKey) rsaKeyFac.generatePublic(rsaPubKeySpec);

    System.out.println("Key extracted, public part: " + rsaPubKey);
    }

    private static byte[] getFileBytes(String path)
    {
        File f = new File(path);
        int sizecontent = ((int) f.length()); // no key file will ever be bigger than 4GiB...
        byte[] data = new byte[sizecontent];
        try 
            {
            FileInputStream freader = new FileInputStream(f);
            freader.read(data, 0, sizecontent) ;
            freader.close();
            return data;
            }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println(ioe.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 8, you can create a PKCS#12 keystore and pass an explicit [PasswordProtection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.PasswordProtection.html#PasswordProtection-char:A-java.lang.String-java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec-) parameter when storing a key to specify the encryption algorithm to use:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStore.PasswordProtection;
import java.security.KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;

public class scratch {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(null, null); // Initialize a blank keystore

        // Your key to store
        PrivateKey key = ...;
        Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[] { ... };

        char[] password = "changeit".toCharArray();
        byte[] salt = new byte[20];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt);
        keyStore.setEntry("test", new PrivateKeyEntry(key, chain),
                          new PasswordProtection(password,
                                                 "PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256",
                                                 new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 100_000)));

        keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/keystore.p12"), password);
    }
}
```

You can read a bit more on the details in [this article](https://neilmadden.wordpress.com/2017/11/17/java-keystores-the-gory-details/) (dislaimer: I wrote that article).

Answer (score 1):

Triple DES is pretty strong, and Oracle likely uses keys with 168 bit of entropy (giving a full 112 bits of security at the time of writing).

Furthermore, although MD5 *may* not be secure for e.g. signatures, it is certainly valid for use in a key derivation scheme as such as PBE.

Of course it would be a good idea for Oracle to migrate away from these schemes in time, but Triple DES and MD5 should not worry you needlessly. Writing your own is probably a worse idea, there are too many pitfalls.

Choose a good password, it's probably the best thing you can do. Or put your keystore in a correctly configured HSM or smartcard if you want high end security.

Comment: I've been contemplating to review and rewrite the keystore used by Java (adding integrity checks and a better indication if the password is incorrect) but I've been applying cryptography for more than 11 years now.

Comment: While 3DES is pretty strong and MD5 as key derivation is just as such, it's situation for *now*, not for what will be in next 10 years (the low end estimate for my application lifetime). MD5 may be broken just as MD4 is tomorrow. It's not like it's a impenetrable hash it once was. Besides, NIST suggest that we should be moving away from SHA1 as a MAC function, let alone MD5...

Comment: True, but if you want us to move away, maybe you are better off creating a protocol, asking the community to review it, implement it and send it to Oracle. This would probably better than creating your own private scheme and hope it survives in the wild. It is the incorrect *application* of algorithms that is much more dangerous than algorithms that have less than 128 bits of security.

Comment: I completely agree. I've read my copy of "Practical Crypography" :) That's why I want to use an already used standard, just with different ciphers. Bouncy Castle already has an "UBER" jks key store, but it uses SHA1 and Twofish. I don't think I'll make it insecure just by changing its cipher to AES and SHA-2 (it's literally a change of one String constant).

Comment: Not sure if the Oracle implementation of PBE will run with SHA-2 (it didn't use to), but I guess that would be a sensible aproach. It depends on the rest of the protocol if it adds much security, but I cannot think of a situation where it could make it worse security wise.

Comment: I'm already using Bouncy Castle for nearly whole crypto in the application so using it for PBE too won't make a difference. As for adding security: SHA256 is slower than SHA1, and that's exactly what we want in key derivation. I'd use `scrypt` for KDF if I could but beggars can't be choosers.

Answer (score 0):

**Main Class**

```
`public class a {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String b = "MSISDN=559915129&productID=5859";

    AEScryptography enj = new AEScryptography();
    String[] argts = {b, "EN"};
    System.out.println("ENCY -> "+enj.encryptionDecryption(argts));
    System.out.println(checksum.encode(b));
} }`
```

**AEScryptography Class**

```
`public class AEScryptography {
public String encryptionDecryption(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, ShortBufferException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    String returnVariable = "";
    if (args.length == 2) {
        try {
            String keystorePass = "201774";  // KeyStroe Password
            String keyPass = "mc7129";       // KeyPassword 
            String alias = "raVi";           // Alias

        InputStream keystoreStream = new FileInputStream("D:/keyFile.jks");
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
            keystore.load(keystoreStream, keystorePass.toCharArray());
            Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, keyPass.toCharArray());
            byte[] bt = key.getEncoded();
            String s = new String(bt);
            String originalString = args[0];
            switch (args[1]) {
                case "EN":
                    String encryptedString = AES.encrypt(originalString, s, bt);
                    returnVariable = encryptedString;
                    break;
                case "DE":
                    String decryptedString = AES.decrypt(originalString, s, bt);
                    returnVariable = decryptedString;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("java -jar /home/jocg/AES-256Encryption.jar StringToEncrypt/Decrypt EN/DE");
                    break;
            }

        } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);

        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("java -jar /home/jocg/AES-256Encryption.jar StringToEncrypt/Decrypt EN/DE");
    }
    return returnVariable;
} }`
```

**AES Class**

```
 public class AES {
private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
private static byte[] key;
public static void setKey(String myKey, byte[] ActualKey) throws 
NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    try {
        key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        key = ActualKey;
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    }
}

public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret, byte[] bt) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    try {
        setKey(secret, bt);
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        SecretKey secKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey, ivspec);
        byte[] newData = cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(newData);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
 }`
```

Comment: Yes sure tomorrow I will update that code with comment