# How do I protect my Java AES encryption key

Tags: java, encryption

I am implementing a program to encrypt string using AES encryption and would like to save my "secret key" in a file instead of hardcoding it in the source code.

But, it creates a problem for me, is how do I protect this secret key from viewed by others?

If I were to encrypt this "keyFile" again, I would have to deal with the same problem again.

How do I deal with such issues?

```
String keyFile = ...;
byte[] keyb = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(keyFile));
SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(keyb, "AES");



import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.security.*;

class Msc61 {
    public static SecretKey generateKey() {
        try {
            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            kgen.init(128);
            return kgen.generateKey();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public static byte[] encrypt_cbc(SecretKey skey, String plaintext) {
        /* Precond: skey is valid; otherwise IllegalStateException will be thrown. */
        try {
            byte[] ciphertext = null;
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");           
            final int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
            byte[] initVector = new byte[blockSize];
            (new SecureRandom()).nextBytes(initVector);
            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initVector);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey, ivSpec);
            byte[] encoded = plaintext.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            ciphertext = new byte[initVector.length + cipher.getOutputSize(encoded.length)];
            for (int i=0; i < initVector.length; i++) {
                ciphertext[i] = initVector[i];
            }
            // Perform encryption
            cipher.doFinal(encoded, 0, encoded.length, ciphertext, initVector.length);
            return ciphertext;
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | ShortBufferException |
            BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            /* None of these exceptions should be possible if precond is met. */
            throw new IllegalStateException(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public static String decrypt_cbc(SecretKey skey, byte[] ciphertext)
        throws BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException /* these indicate corrupt or malicious ciphertext */
    {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");           
            final int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
            byte[] initVector = Arrays.copyOfRange(ciphertext, 0, blockSize);
            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initVector);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, ivSpec);
            byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext, blockSize, ciphertext.length - blockSize);
            return new String(plaintext);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException |
            InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            /* None of these exceptions should be possible if precond is met. */
            throw new IllegalStateException(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Ref: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/MSC61-J.+Do+not+use+insecure+or+weak+cryptographic+algorithms

Comment: A fuller understanding of your system might provide some hints to a solution. First off, why are you encrypting the data? Who are you trying to keep it secret from? Why aren't you using a user-entered password to protect the user's data?

Comment: Secret keys are typically stored inside a Keystore which asks for authentication to decrypt the secret key and provide it to the program.  Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html

Comment: @AhmedMasud You just moved the secret to the keystore. Now how do you keep the authentication of the keystore secret?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk okay, my application needs to access the database. it requires username and password authentication. I need to encrypt and decrypt the password stored in the properties file.

Answer (score 3):

You have several options to do this.

If you actually need to encrypt your key, you can use a JCEKS keystore to store it in an encrypted form. This keystore is well suited or, better said, can be used, for storing a single key. You can see an example of how to use it in this DZone [article](https://dzone.com/articles/aes-256-encryption-java-and). It will give you an explanation about what is going on under the hoods, and will provide you some background about this kind of keystore.

You can also encrypt directly your key by using a Password Based Encryption algorithm. [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864696/how-to-create-java-key-store-jks-file-with-aes-encryption) will provide you a good example of hoe to implement this kind of solution.

If your requirement is only encrypt and decrypt properties in a properties file as you indicated in your comments, you can use [Jasypt](http://jasypt.org). This library is in fact a wrapper of several cryptographic solutions.

As you can see in their [documentation](http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html), this library will provide you [some utilities](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/properties/EncryptableProperties.html) for a general use case.

Consider the following example, obtained from the links above, and very well suited for your needs. They provide a properties file:

```
datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/reportsdb
datasource.username=reportsUser
datasource.password=ENC(G6N718UuyPE5bHyWKyuLQSm02auQPUtm)
```

And they show how to read this properties:

```java
/*
  * First, create (or ask some other component for) the adequate encryptor for
  * decrypting the values in our .properties file.
  */
 StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
 encryptor.setPassword("jasypt"); // could be got from web, env variable...
 encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithHMACSHA512AndAES_256");
 encryptor.setIvGenerator(new RandomIvGenerator());
 
 /*
  * Create our EncryptableProperties object and load it the usual way.
  */
 Properties props = new EncryptableProperties(encryptor);
 props.load(new FileInputStream("/path/to/my/configuration.properties"));

 /*
  * To get a non-encrypted value, we just get it with getProperty...
  */
 String datasourceUsername = props.getProperty("datasource.username");

 /*
  * ...and to get an encrypted value, we do exactly the same. Decryption will
  * be transparently performed behind the scenes.
  */ 
 String datasourcePassword = props.getProperty("datasource.password");

 // From now on, datasourcePassword equals "reports_passwd"...
```

If you are using Spring, it will also give you a [great framework integration](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt).

As you can see, independently of the solution adopted, you will always need a password that actually protect your key.

The best way you can provide this password to the different mechanisms described above is by defining it as an environment variable: the idea is that this information will be visible only for systems administrator and the IT people responsible of the maintenance of your server software.

On the other hand, all the major Cloud providers (AWS, GCP, Azure, ...) will give you services (KMS for the first two, and Key Vault for Azure) that allows you to safely encrypt and decrypt information even without having access to the actual key: in these scenarios the use of these services probably will be the better approach.

Comment: @ilovetolearn I provide you an example of using Jasypt obtained from the library documentation. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: if you are defending your key against reverse engineering then you can't do much, almost every security system can be cracked after some time. but you can make it hard for the crackers by using nested encryption algorithms and obsecuring techniques.
You can try:

1. Generate key in runtime.
2. Split and store key as parts in different places. Eg. Server and Device.
3. 2FA Two Factor Authentication.
4. Making keys Expire before they can be cracked.
5. Security through Obsecurity.

Finally, remember that every security can be cracked, And you can only make it harder for them.

Answer (score 0):

My best answer is injecting the key at **runtime**. My system uses Spring-boot on Kubernetes. Therefore, you can use Kube'Secrets to keep the key and inject it when the app starts via Env. The only way that bad actor can get the key by somehow **hack** the app. Moreover, the beauty of microservice is you can separately create encrypt/decrypt microservice and use the robust language and libraries. Maybe, Rust?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using environment properties

- let suppose you 2 environments of your code, 1 for development and another for production
- Now you need to create a environment variable which will be hold file path, like if you are using Linux based system then you can set this variable in bashrc or inside profile.

eg;

```
secret.private.key.path=home-directory/secret/private.key
secret.public.key.path=home-directory/secret/public.key
```

- You will create 2 public, private key pair, one used in development (any developer can access it whom are working with you (shared)) and another used in production so production  based private key always secure as only authorized person have access of production.
- Inside of your code System.getenv method which will retuen that env variable

  ```
  String privateKeyPath = System.getenv("secret.private.key.path")
    String publicKeyPath = System.getenv("secret.public.key.path")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, your best option is to use a key container store. This assumes that the application's user context can be trusted. If you can't, all bets are off  because these solutions work on the basis of trusting the user context. If you cannot trust the application's user context, you have bigger problems than just the compromised keystore access. So, think about your application's security holistically. The solutions below address key storage on various platforms. If you are concerned about other apps running in the user's context somehow accessing the keystore, take a look at rolling your own.

**Key storage solutions**

For Java: [Java Keystore for Storing and Retrieving sensitive strings (Redhat)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/create_a_java_keystore_to_store_sensitive_strings)

For Windows: [Key Storage and Retrieval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/key-storage-and-retrieval)

For MacOS: [Storing Keys in the Secure Enclave](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_secure_enclave)

For Android: [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore)

For NodeJS: [keytar: A native Node module to get, add, replace, and delete passwords in system's keychain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keytar)

**Rolling your own**

If you want to roll your own, you can do that by implementing a service. There are pros and cons to this approach, but it gives you flexibility.

1. Your service will generate the keys
2. Client and service communicate using Diffie-Hellman key exchange to exchange a shared secret. This shared secret acts as an ephemeral key (i.e., transient key) and can be discarded after a single transaction.
3. The service encrypts the generated key (key wrapping) using the shared secret and sends it to client
4. Client decrypts the wrapped key to recover the secret key
5. Service stores the secret key in an associative map that maps client public id => secret key (encrypted). The secret key is encrypted using another long-lived secret key that is known only to the server (for eg: the private key of its public key certificate). If you want to store multiple keys per client, model it accordingly ie., the associative map becomes <client public id, key name> => <secret key (encrypted)>

You will need to add a mechanism to authenticate the client (by the server) and server (by the client) to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks. Although the Diffie-Hellman key exchange can be run over an insecure protocol such as plain TCP or HTTP, you can get additional level of security by running it under HTTPS and server authentication (since HTTPS uses public key certificates).