# Using java keytool to encrypt imported paswords with PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128

Tags: java, java-8, keystore, keytool

I am looking to store sensitive passwords in a java keystore using java keytool's importpass. I am using Oracle java version 1.8.0_212, and cannot upgrade from java 8 at the moment.

I have created a PKCS12 keystore with the following command:

`keytool -keystore test-keystore.p12 -genkey -storetype PKCS12 -alias test`

I then imported a password into the keystore using:

`keytool -importpass -storetype pkcs12 -alias protectedPass -keystore test-keystore.p12`

This worked, but this uses the encryption algorithm "PBEWithMD5AndDES" by default, which isn't particularly secure. I am now trying to use "PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128" from the Java Security Standard Algorithm Names doc but having issues getting this to work.

I've tried specifying the keyalg like this:

`keytool -importpass -keyalg PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128 -storetype pkcs12 -alias protectedPass -keystore test-keystore.p12 -v`

and while this doesn't cause an error, it doesn't seem to actually affect the output. The secret is key still generated with PBEWithMD5AndDES:

```
D:\temp>keytool -importpass -keyalg PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128 -storetype pkcs12 -alias protectedPass -keystore test-keystore.p12 -v
Enter keystore password:
Enter the password to be stored:
Re-enter password:
Generated PBEWithMD5AndDES secret key
[Storing test-keystore.p12]
```

I can see examples, such as in [Java Keystores the Gory Details](https://neilmadden.blog/2017/11/17/java-keystores-the-gory-details/), of people using KeyStore.PasswordProtection to use algorithms like this, but I wanted to use the keytool if possible.

Am I missing something key here or trying to do something silly?

**EDIT:**

Tried to do something similar programmatically to figure out what I'm doing wrong and had no luck using PKCS12 keystores with this algorithm. However, jceks seems to work. I think this is to do with it using the SunJCE provider instead. Is there some parameter I am missing to get this algorithm working with pcks12? Or is there some other approach I could take?

I have provided some simple demo code below. If you swap "JCEKS" for "PKCS12" it will throw `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: unrecognized algorithm name: PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128`.

**Demo Code:**

```java
static void encrypt() throws Exception {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
    keyStore.load(null, "changeit".toCharArray());
    KeyStore.PasswordProtection keyStorePP = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("changeit".toCharArray());

    SecretKeyFactory pbeKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");
    SecretKey pbeKey = pbeKeyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec("testpassword".toCharArray()));

    keyStore.setEntry(SECRET_KEY_ALIAS, new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(
            pbeKey), keyStorePP);

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_PATH);
    keyStore.store(outputStream, "changeit".toCharArray());
}

static void decrypt() throws Exception {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(FILE_PATH);
    keyStore.load(fileInputStream, "changeit".toCharArray());

    KeyStore.PasswordProtection keyStorePP = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("changeit".toCharArray());

    KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry ske =
            (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry)keyStore.getEntry(SECRET_KEY_ALIAS, keyStorePP);

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");
    PBEKeySpec keySpec = (PBEKeySpec)factory.getKeySpec(
            ske.getSecretKey(),
            PBEKeySpec.class);

    System.out.println(new String(keySpec.getPassword()));
}
```

Comment: Not sure if `-sigalg`has any bearing on this - perhaps it could. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#AppA

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep separate the algorithm a key is for and the way it is protected.

A Java keystore (depending on type, including JCEKS and PKCS12 but not JKS) can [contain three kinds of entries](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html). A SecretKeyEntry in general contains a secret *key* which is typically valid for a particular cipher algorithm, identified in the `SecretKey` object within the entry. But for *password-based* algorithms, the 'key' object is actually a generic 'PBEKey' which contains a password and AFAICT can be used for any PBE algorithm. It appears the 'algorithm' for such keys is actually stored as PBEwithMD5andDES, I suspect because that's the only scheme from original PKCS5 (i.e. PBES1) Java implements. However, *my* Oracle 8u212 keytool says more generically `Generated PBE secret key` in this case, not `PBEwithMD5andDES` as you show.

The stored secret key (and stored private key also) can be and normally is 'protected' *in the keystore* by being encrypted with a password-based encryption algorithm; this 'protection' algorithm is different from and in general not related to the algorithm(s) that the key or password will be used with after retrieval.

`keytool -importpass -keyalg PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128` attempts to specify the algorithm the key-really-password is nominally to be *used with* when retrieved, but not how it is protected, which for PKCS12 in most older versions including **yours is actually PBE-SHA1-TripleDES** (the same as for privatekeys) -- you can see this, with a little work, using OpenSSL. And in *my* 8u212 `keytool` specifying `-keyalg` *fails* for PKCS12 with an exception claiming it can't protect because there are no parameters for that algorithm (although I think the problem is serializing, not actually encrypting) much as you say your code does for PKCS12, but Java does have these parameters -- although in a different provider (SunJCE vs SunJSSE) which might be messing it up somehow; as you say JCEKS is in SunJCE.
Similarly your code generates a key *to be used with* that algorithm, but protected the default way. To change the *protection* you need to specify it in `PasswordProtection`, as stated in the page you link; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47389384/ (by the same author) for an example.

*Recent* versions of Java -- 8u301 and 11.0.12 up -- have a new feature to configure the protection algorithms for PKCS12 with security properties in the `java.security` file which is in `JRE/lib/security` for 8 down or `JRE/conf/security` for 9 up. This applies to both code you write if not overridden as above, and to keytool (which can't override). However, those versions (except for 12 through 16, which are now EOL) also now default to PBEwithHmacSHA256andAES_256 which is already better than you asked for, so **you probably don't need to change anything -- just use 8u301 up**.

Note JCEKS uses a Sun-defined PBE-MD5-TripleDES similar to, but not, PBES1, while JKS doesn't support secretkey entries but for privatekey entries uses a deliberately weak (ITAR-friendly back in the 1990s) Sun-custom algorithm; these cannot be changed.